# Elm: How to Json decode a Union Type with a single TypeConstructor?

Tags: json, decode, elm, type-constructor, union-types

As seen in following code, it is easy to decode UserAlias but the moment I try to decode UserType i.e. Replace `D.map2 UserAlias` with `D.map2 UserType` Compiler cries out loud. How do I fix this compiler error?

```
import Json.Decode as D
import Html exposing (..)
import Result as R

type  UserType = UserType {name:String, age:Int}

type alias UserAlias = {name:String, age:Int}


userDecoder = D.map2 UserAlias
                (D.field "name" D.string)
                (D.field "age" D.int)


decodeUser json = D.decodeString userDecoder json 


json = """
  { "name": "Bob", "age": 40 }
"""


main = div [] [(text << toString << decodeUser) json]
```

Above code works fine. Now replace `D.map2 UserAlias` with `D.map2 UserType`

And compiler cries

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
==================================== ERRORS ====================================



-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------------

The 2nd argument to function `map2` is causing a mismatch.

13|               D.map2 UserType
14|>                (D.field "name" D.string)
15|                 (D.field "age" D.int)

Function `map2` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    D.Decoder { age : Int, name : String }

But it is:

    D.Decoder String

Hint: I always figure out the type of arguments from left to right. If an
argument is acceptable when I check it, I assume it is "correct" in subsequent
checks. So the problem may actually be in how previous arguments interact with
the 2nd.



-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------------

The 1st argument to function `map2` is causing a mismatch.

13|>              D.map2 UserType
14|                 (D.field "name" D.string)
15|                 (D.field "age" D.int)

Function `map2` is expecting the 1st argument to be:

    { age : Int, name : String } -> b -> UserType

But it is:

    { age : Int, name : String } -> UserType

Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.
```

How do I fix this error, please help!

Basically I nolonger wish to use type alias, and only user UserType so that I can hide internal record structure, and refactor it without breaking the public API.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UserType` constructor takes a single parameter of `UserAlias`, so we can simply use `Json.Decode.map` inside your existing decoder to take the `UserAlias` value and construct a decoder for `UserType` like this:

```elm
userDecoder : D.Decoder UserType
userDecoder = D.map2 UserAlias
                (D.field "name" D.string)
                (D.field "age" D.int)
                |> D.map UserType
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You are a life saver as always :D Now I can finally use Type Constructors to hide implementation structure.

Comment: But this still uses type alias, OP was looking for a solution without type alias

Answer (score 5):

A slightly more direct way than Chad's answer would be to do this in the `map2` function:

```
userDecoder : D.Decoder UserType
userDecoder = D.map2 (\name age -> UserType <| UserAlias name age)
                (D.field "name" D.string)
                (D.field "age" D.int)
```

This will avoid the pattern match in the second `map`. It probably not going to buy you much in terms of performance here, though!

If you are feeling like being a little more terse, this can also be written in a pointfree style:

```
userDecoder = D.map2 (((<<) UserType ) << UserAlias)
                (D.field "name" D.string)
                (D.field "age" D.int)
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciated your answer, as it helps me understand better how these API's work. Hopefully, I will be able to learn and embrace such patterns in my code.

Although, for practical purposes I will use Chad's Answer ;)